# docker.local hostname in /etc/hosts not resolving on OSX for docker machine (causing rspec tests to fail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, rspec, docker, docker-machine

I had a bug today where my rspec tests ran fine, down to the last expectation, but then I still got a "database connection timeout error".

This is running rails locally, connecting to a postgres instance inside of docker, using docker machine.

Docker machine instructions guided me to create an entry in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
192.168.99.100 docker.local
```

This worked fine for the test itself, but then something (probably some cleanup step after the test suite - possibly from DatabaseCleaner?) still raised an error about timing out connecting to the database.

After a lot of investigation, debugging, even deleting and recreating the docker machine default container, I finally narrowed it down to if I replace `docker.local` with the actual IP address in the database config - it passes.

So bottom line - some cleanup process didn't have access to the /etc/hosts defined docker.local hostname.

This is on OSX El Capitan.